# Lebesgue measure of a neighbourhood of a curve

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open, bounded and with smooth boundary (e.g. Lipschitz boundary or more if necessary).

For any function $\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\ \phi\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ with:

$\bullet\ \phi^{-1}(0)=\{x\in\Omega\ |\ \phi(x)=0\}\neq\emptyset$

$\bullet\ \nabla\phi(x)\neq 0,\ \forall\ x\in \phi^{-1}(0)$

we define the sets $V_{\varepsilon}$ (neighbourhoods of $\phi^{-1}(0)$) and $L_{\delta}$ (all the levels between $-\delta$ and $\delta$) by:

$$V_{\varepsilon}:=\{x\in\Omega\ |\ \mathrm{dist}(x,\phi^{-1}(0))\leq \varepsilon\}$$

and

$$L_{\delta}:=\{x\in\Omega \ \big |\ |\phi(x)|<\delta\}$$

where $\mathrm{dist}(x,\phi^{-1}(0)):=\displaystyle\inf_{y\in \phi^{-1}(0)} |x-y|$.

How can we prove that:

**1)** $\lambda(V_{\varepsilon})=2\varepsilon \cdot \text{Perimeter}( \phi^{-1}(0)),\ \forall\ \varepsilon>0$

**2)** For each $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $\delta_0>0$ such that:

$$L_{\delta}\subseteq V_{\varepsilon},\ \forall\ \delta\in (0,\delta_0)$$

---

Here $\lambda$ means the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

$\overline{\Omega}$ is the closure of $\Omega$.

$C^1$ means the Banach space of continuously differentiable functions.

My interest is specially on the case $N=2$ in which $\phi^{-1}(0)$ can be viewed as a implicit regular curve and $V_{\varepsilon}$ as a neighbourhood of it. I think the conclusions I've made are very natural but I don't have a proof yet.

**P.S. It is known that $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is a set with $C^1$ boundary so it has a finite perimeter.**

Comment: Formula 1) is only asymptotically correct. Imagine that $\Omega$ is the unit disk  $\{ x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $\phi(x,y)=y$ so $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is the horizontal diameter with perimeter $2$.. Then $\lambda(V_\varepsilon)<4\varepsilon$ yet $\lambda(V_\varepsilon)=4\varepsilon +O(\varepsilon^2)$. In general, for a closed  $C^2$-curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$  the tube formula states that $\lambda(V_\varepsilon)=length(C)\varepsilon^{n-1}\omega_{n-1}$, where $\omega_{n-1}$ is the volume of the unit $(n-1)$-dimensional ball.Question 2 is standard.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Please, can you provide some references where I can find such things?

Comment: All the proofs require quite a bit of Riemannian geometry.  Check Sec. 9.3.3 of these notes  https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf For curves the proof simplifies   quite a bit. Here is Weyl's original paper http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/AAT-readings/Data%20Analysis%20/Tubes/Weyl,%20volume%20of%20tubes.pdf